# UIImageview frame seems to not be updating

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create an UIImageview to represent how full the buffer is with data.

So the UIImageview is hidden to start with as the buffer is empty and as the buffer fills I proportionally want to show more and more of the buffer UIImageview.

So the values to calculate the size of the frame is correct I checked the values with NSLog and they look good and are changing as the buffer increases in size, but it seems to not effect the frame on screen when I update the frame with the newly calculated values.

```
-(void) animateBuffer
{
    bufferImage.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, y , 20, height);
}
```

the animateBuffer function gets called every second as I set up a timer in my viewDidLoad.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(animateBuffer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Anybody able to point me in the right direction? In what I am doing wrong here or a better way to approach this problem?

The buffer view (it is actually a ViewController not a view) is from an XIB.

The parent View Controller has a Table and a view. This view is where I load and display the Buffer view controller with the following code.

```
UIViewController *childViewController = [[BufferVC alloc]init]; 
[self addChildViewController:childViewController];
[self.radioView addSubview:childViewController.view];
[childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

If I was using a storyboard I would use a containerview, but because I cant with XIB I did what is above.

Comment: How did you create the view? Via storyboard or with code? What content mode have you set on the imageview?

Comment: Edited the question to answer your questions @Paulw11

Comment: Your view is most likely set under auto layout constraints. When using auto layout you cannot update the frame manually.

Comment: So now your code is more confusing.  You are adding a child view controller; why don't you just add the buffer view as a subview to your existing view?  You still don't show how you actually created the `bufferImage` object, but I am going to assume it is through code.  Most importantly, what `contentMode` have you set on that image view?

Comment: @fogmeister you were bang on the money. As soon as I disabled auto layout for the XIB it started updating as you would expect. If you can put that in an answer I will accept it so the next person to experience this problem will be helped. Thanks again ;)

Comment: @Code you have taken my comment and done the exact opposite of what you are supposed to. The answer is not to disable auto layout. The answer is to learn how to use auto layout.